# A special matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine $X \in M(\mathbb{R})$ such that:

$X^2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

My attempt to solution:

I could not find any method to descovery the real solutions for X.

$1$) Define $A = X^2$,  $A$ is a symmetric matrix that implies $A$ is diagonalizable.

$2$) So, I find the eigenvalues of $A: -1, -1, 2$

$3$) With the eigenvalues of $A$, I found eigenvectors associated to each eigenvalue, and thus a invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P*D_A*P^{-1}$.

$P =\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$D_A =\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$,
$P^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix} -1/3 & 2/3 & -1/3 \\-1/3 & -1/3 & 2/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \end{bmatrix}$

$4$) Now we need to find the eigenvalues of $X$, because if we suppose that $X$ is diagonalizable, so thus have the same matrix $P$ like: $X = P*D_x*P^{-1}$ implies that $X^2 = P*D_x ^{2}*P^{-1}$ and $D_x ^{2} = D_A$.

By Spectral Mapping Theorem:
We know that every eigenvalue of $X$ belongs to the set $\{-i,i,\sqrt2,-\sqrt2\}$

Remenber that $X \in M(\mathbb{R})$, so the caracteristic polynomial has only real coefficients, implies that in summary the eingenvalues of $X$ have two possibilites: $i,-i, \sqrt2$ or $i, -i, -\sqrt2 $

$5$) Define:

$D_x,_1 =\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \\0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \end{bmatrix}$, $D_x,_2 =\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \\0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\sqrt2 \end{bmatrix}$, $D_x,_3 =\begin{bmatrix} -i & 0 & 0 \\0 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \end{bmatrix}$, $D_x,_4 =\begin{bmatrix} -i & 0 & 0 \\0 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\sqrt2 \end{bmatrix}$

Look that any $D_x ^2 = D_A$.

$6$) It should be easy now, right?

$X_1 = P*D_x,_1*P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt2/3 & (\sqrt2 -3i)/3 & (\sqrt2 +3i)/3 \\(\sqrt2 -i)/3 & (\sqrt2 +2i)/3 & (\sqrt2 -i)/3 \\ (\sqrt2 +i)/3 & (\sqrt2 +i)/3 & (\sqrt2 -2i)/3 \end{bmatrix}$

$X_2 = P*D_x,_2*P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt2/3 & (-\sqrt2 -3i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 +3i)/3 \\(-\sqrt2 -i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 +2i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 -i)/3 \\ (-\sqrt2 +i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 +i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 -2i)/3 \end{bmatrix}$

$X_3 = P*D_x,_3*P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt2/3 & (\sqrt2 +3i)/3 & (\sqrt2 -3i)/3 \\(\sqrt2 +i)/3 & (\sqrt2 -2i)/3 & (\sqrt2 +i)/3 \\ (\sqrt2 -i)/3 & (\sqrt2 -i)/3 & (\sqrt2 +2i)/3 \end{bmatrix}$

$X_4 = P*D_x,_4*P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt2/3 & (-\sqrt2 +3i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 -3i)/3 \\(-\sqrt2 +i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 -2i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 +i)/3 \\ (-\sqrt2 -i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 -i)/3 & (-\sqrt2 +2i)/3 \end{bmatrix}$

Look that any $X^2 = A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$7$) Remember $X \in M(\mathbb{R})$, and $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 \notin M(\mathbb{R})$. By that moment, I thought that maybe there is no $X \in M(\mathbb{R})$ such that $X^2 = A$. Because of that I tried to guess a solution and I descover this one:

$X = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt2 & -1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & \sqrt2 -1 \\ -1 & \sqrt2 +1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Its easy to check that its correct, $X^2 = A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$8$) But it is just a solution, and I dont know how to find all real solutions without guessing. I have seen other problems such as this one on this website, but none of the answers I found has a satisfactory solution for $X \in M(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s just use transformed coordinates and then as: When is $X^2=\mathrm{diag}(-1,-1,2)$? This is exactly the case if for the rows $r_i$ and columns $c_j$ of $X$ we have:
$$ r_ic_j = 0$$
if $i\neq j$ and else $-1$ for $i=j=1,2$ or $2$ if $i=j=3$. This results in a system of $9$ quadratic equations in $9$ variables.

If we take the Ideal of the corresponding polynomial ring and calculate a groebner basis for the lexicographic term order, we get:
$$\left[x_{11}^{2} - x_{22}^{2}, x_{11} x_{12} + x_{12} x_{22}, x_{11} x_{21} + x_{21} x_{22}, x_{11} x_{22}^{2} + x_{11} + x_{22}^{3} + x_{22}, x_{12} x_{21} + x_{22}^{2} + 1, x_{13}, x_{23}, x_{31}, x_{32}, x_{33}^{2} - 2\right]$$
So any solution must have $x_{33}=\pm\sqrt{2}$, $x_{32}=x_{31}=x_{23}=x_{13} =0$.

Then $x_{11}=\pm x_{22}$.
If $x_{11}=0$ we get $x_{12}x_{21}=-1$,or $x_{12}=-1/x_{21}$.

If $x_1=-x_2$ the second, third and fourth polynomal cancel to $0$, and we remain with $x_{12}x_{21} + x_{22}^2 +1 =0 $ or $x_{22} = \pm \sqrt{-1-x_{12}x_{21}}$.

Lastly if $x_{11}=x_{22}\neq 0$ we immediately get $x_{12}=0=x_{21}$ and then $x_{22}^2=-1$.

This gives us then the following three forms for $X$:
$$ X=\begin{pmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & i & 0 \\ 0&0&\pm\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix},\qquad X=\begin{pmatrix} -i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -i & 0 \\ 0&0&\pm\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
or
$$ X=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x & 0 \\ -1/x & 0 & 0 \\ 0&0&\pm\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{s.t. $x\neq0$}$$
or
$$ X=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{-1-xy} & x & 0 \\ y & -\sqrt{-1-xy} & 0 \\ 0&0&\pm\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix},\quad X=\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{-1-xy} & x & 0 \\ y & \sqrt{-1-xy} & 0 \\ 0&0&\pm\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{with arbitrary $x,y$} $$

One can easily verify that all of these three forms satisfy $X^2=\mathrm{diag}(-1,-1,2)$.

EDIT: The real solutions then are given by form 2 and by form three only if $-1-xy\geq0$, so $xy\geq -1$. Your example solutions transforms to
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt2 -1 & -2 & 0 \\ -\sqrt2+2 & -\sqrt2+1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
So this is form 3 with $x=-2$, $y=2-\sqrt2$, $-1-xy=-1+4-2\sqrt2 = 3-2\sqrt2>0$. This can be expressed as $1^2-2\cdot1\cdot\sqrt2+\sqrt2^2=(1-\sqrt2)^2$.